# Matlab curve fitting tool, cftool, generate code function does not give the same fit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am using Matlab's curve fitting tool, `cftool`, to fit a set of points which I have. The problem I am facing is that the generate code function will not give me the same fit as produced in the `cftool`.

This is not what I want because I want to be able to retrieve the data from the residual plot. I could also just copy the function from `cftool` and do it manually. But I do not understand why the generated code will not just give me the same curve fit.

The `cftool` session file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20782274/test.sfit

The generated code from Matlab:

```
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit1(Velocity, kWhPerkm)
%CREATEFIT1(VELOCITY,KWHPERKM)
%  Create a fit.
%
%  Data for 'untitled fit 3' fit:
%      X Input : Velocity
%      Y Output: kWhPerkm
%  Output:
%      fitresult : a fit object representing the fit.
%      gof : structure with goodness-of fit info.
%
%  See also FIT, CFIT, SFIT.

%  Auto-generated by MATLAB on 02-Dec-2012 16:36:19


%% Fit: 'untitled fit 3'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( Velocity, kWhPerkm );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'a/(0.008*x) + c*x^2 + d*90', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.DiffMaxChange = 0.01;
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.Lower = [-Inf -Inf -Inf];
opts.MaxFunEvals = 1000;
opts.MaxIter = 1000;
opts.StartPoint = [0 0 0];
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf Inf];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );

% Create a figure for the plots.
figure( 'Name', 'untitled fit 3' );

% Plot fit with data.
subplot( 2, 1, 1 );
plot( fitresult, xData, yData, 'predobs' );
% Label axes
xlabel( 'Velocity' );
ylabel( 'kWhPerkm' );
grid on

% Plot residuals.
subplot( 2, 1, 2 );
plot( fitresult, xData, yData, 'residuals' );
% Label axes
xlabel( 'Velocity' );
ylabel( 'kWhPerkm' );
grid on
```

The curve I get with the generated code: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/65d1P.jpg

The curve I need: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Egp.jpg

So does anyone know what goes wrong?

-edit-
And the Velocity and WhPerkm data file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20782274/data.mat

Comment: When I use the data from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20782274/data.mat in CFTOOL, I get what looks like a good fit: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DnUND.png.

When I use the data in the session (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20782274/test.sfit ) and the generated code, I get another good fit: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O9USJ.png.

Can you check the data that you using with the generated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE: *I want to be able to retrieve the data from the residual plot*

One way to do this is:

1. Select "Save to Workspace..." from the Fit menu
2. Ensure that "Save fit output to MATLAB struct named" is checked.
3. Note the name of variable. By default, it is `output`.
4. Click "OK" to send data to the MATLAB workspace.

In the MATLAB workspace, the residuals will be in `output.residuals`. For your example, you can plot the residuals via, e.g.,

```
>> plot( Velocity, output.residuals, '.' )
```